How to compensate tilted accelerometer?
First of all, I only have accelerometer to solve this problem.
I have tilted accelerometer mounted in a vehicle, and I like to get the output values of this accelerometer as if this accelerometer is mounted in level (flat).
For example, each axis's output values of level accelerometer would be as below. (ignored small errors)
[Flat] X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 1 (stationary)
But when the accelerometer is tilted which is in my case, the output values would be,
[Tilt] X = +0.4, Y = -0.3, Z = +0.85 (stationary)
Values of above are when the vehicle is stationary. And let's say the vehicle has accelerated. (0 -> 20 miles/h forward)
For the level accelerometer, the output values of X or Y will be changed (value of Z would not change)
[Flat] X = 0.5, Y = 0, Z = 1 or (0 -> 20 miles/h forward)
[Flat] X = 0, Y = 0.5, Z = 1 etc.. (0 -> 20 miles/h forward)
And for the tilted acceleromter in same situation, (20 miles/h forward) it would be like below,
[Tilt] X = 0.98, Y = -0.2, Z = +0.6 (0 -> 20 miles/h forward)
values could be little different. I mean, all the values of 3 axes will change.
And in this situation, what I would like to do is, I would like to get the values of [Tilt] as [Flat].
I mean I would like to convert the output of
[Tilt] X = 0.98, Y = -0.2, Z = +0.6 (0 -> 20 miles/h forward) to [Flat] X = 0.5, Y = 0, Z = 1 (0 -> 20 miles/h forward)
I want convert every value of [Tilt] to [Flat].
To achieve my goal, what kind of calculation is needed? I know simple addition and subtraction is not the answer for this.
I heard that "Translation Matrix" and "quaternion" is useful for this case, I feel difficult to apply in this case. Please teach me how to apply if it is the answer.
Somewhat errors would be OK as long as if I can get rough answer. Thank you for reading my question.
I can provide more information if more details needed.
[Additional Question and Example]
Since I am testing for the Mark H's Transformation Matrix for this, maybe I can add an example for this.
I mounted 2 accelerometer on a same board. One is mounted [Flat], and the other is [Tilted].
And accelerated the board so both [Flat] and [Tilted] accelerometers would get same (at least similar) acceleration.
The values I measured are as belows.

Stationary Value of X, Y, Z axis for both [Flat] and [Tilted]
[Flat] (X=+0.00, Y=+0.00, Z=+1.00)
[Tilted] (X=-0.10, Y=+0.29, Z=+0.90)

I derived the Transformation Matrix of Mark H with the value of [Tilted],
as below.
(Please check if it is correct)

And I accelerated the board and both Accelerometers's value are changed.
(I accelerated for the direction of X axis)

Accelerated Value of X, Y, Z axis for both [Flat] and [Tilted]
(values maybe have some erroes, since the measured timing for both values could be a bit different)

[Flat]   (X=+0.15, Y=+0.07, Z=+1.01)
[Tilted] (X=+0.14, Y=+0.31, Z=+0.91)
I want transform the [Tilted] value to [Flat] value.
Because in my real problem, I only have [Tilted] accelerometer mounted.
if I use the Transformation Matrix on the [Tilted] value and get the [Flat],
I can finally achieve my goal.
the final value for [Flat] maybe can have somewhat errors.
(errors like +-0.1 or 0.2)
But when I use the transformation matrix,
I get as below
[(measured)  Flat]   (X=+0.15, Y=+0.07, Z=+1.01)
[(by matrix) Flat]   (X=-0.23, Y=+0.05, Z=+0.89)
the problem is X axis. It gets totally different value from the measured one.
Did I do something wrong? or do I have to derived a new matrix for the accelerated X, Y, Z values?
[One more Example]

Stationary Value of X, Y, Z axis for both [Flat] and [Tilted]
[Flat] (X=+0.00, Y=+0.00, Z=+1.00)
[Tilted] (X=-0.10, Y=+0.29, Z=+0.90)

Accelerated Value of X, Y, Z axis for both [Flat] and [Tilted]
[Flat]   (X=+1.81, Y=+0.77, Z=+1.03)
[Tilted] (X=+1.05, Y=+0.09, Z=+0.98)

Comparison of calculated [Tilted] to [Flat] and measured [Flat]
(measured) [Flat] (X=+1.81, Y=+0.77, Z=+1.03)
(by matrix)[Flat] (X=-1.02, Y=+0.53, Z=+0.80)\


*I guess I keep getting X axis wrong and it's sign is always different.
If measured is +, I get - for by matrix and vice versa.
Please Help me to find the similar value to the value of measured Flat using the matrix.

Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137455/two-rotation-coordinate-transformation

Thank you. I didn't realize that I actually need just (0, 0, 1) which means I don't need Z axis transformed! I will work on with the post you gave me. I think it could be my answer.

Dear Mark H. your answer perfectly works when the G is 1. But if the car accelerates, G is no longer 1 (but it stays near 1) and if G is not 1, the formula has somewhat errors. I have to make accelerated value of G to 1G. (Vx / |V|, Vy / |V|, Vz / |V|). And then use transform matrix again. Would you know what the transform matrix would be for accelerated value of G?

To derive the matrix, I used a normalized acceleration (magnitude = 1). However, the resulting matrix will transform any vector of any length into the new coordinate system. Because the transformation is just a rotation, the magnitude of the transformed vector will be the same as the original vector. It will help if you edit your question to add an example of the problem you are having.

Dear Mark H. Thank you for helping me. I added some examples that show the values as you adviced. Please check my questions! I hope I described my example clearly. Please tell me if I have to add more example values.

I looked at your measurements and I have a few observations.
First, the flat and tilted acceleration measurements don't have the same magnitude: $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. In your first measurement, the flat acceleration is $[0, 0, 1]$ and tilted acceleration is $[-0.10, 0.29, 0.90]$. The flat acceleration magnitude is 1, while the tilted acceleration magnitude is 0.95. This makes me think that the individual accelerometers for each direction are not perpendicular to each other in the tilted accelerometer assembly. If they were, the two magnitudes would be the same since rotating a vector does not change its magnitude. To check your accelerometers, make sure that there is an orientation that results in two sensors reading zero and that the third reads one (I'm assuming your sensors measure acceleration in units of $g$ so that a reading of 1 corresponds to gravity). If the component accelerometers are perpendicular, then you can use the matrix method in my other answer. If not, try to fix this, because otherwise the math gets much more involved and requires more measurements.
Second, when you create the rotation matrix using my method, the vector you use must be a unit vector: $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = 1.$ Scale $x$, $y$, and $z$ so this is true before creating the matrix. Check that you did the math right by multiplying the resulting matrix by the $xyz$ vector to get $[0, 0, 1].$ You did the math correctly, but with a vector $[x, y, z]$ that was not unit-length.
Third, the changing signs of the corrected tilted measurements make me think it's possible that your two accelerometer assemblies are not both left-handed or both right-handed. If your accelerometers form a right-handed coordinate system, you will be able to orient it like this: (1) x-sensor horizontal pointing to your right, (2) y-sensor horizontal pointing away from you, (3) z-sensor pointing up. Make sure both of your accelerometer assemblies have right-handed arrangements or the math to relate the two will get more involved.

Very good points! I will check your observations one by one with my accelerometers and measures whether I made misses. And I would like to ask you for further issues! Thank you so much.

The question linked by Mark H in the comments has the answer you are looking for.  However, in that question we already assumed that using a 3x3 matrix was the correct way to go.  We even knew how to construct a few useful ones.  Your question indicates that you're not familiar with these matrices, so how might you know to use them?  That seemed worthy of an answer.
You are looking to transform your tilted input into a flat output.  What might that transformation look like?  One of the things that is always worth trying is to see if it is linear.  Linear transformations are one of the easiest kinds of transformations you can work with.  So it's always worth seeing if you just got lucky and got to use one of the easy cases.  It's just one of those things I've learned to always check.  New Problem?  I wonder if it just happens to already be linear.  It's just the way I've learned to think through the years (later on, you will find mathematicians often reshape the problem to make them linear... its that useful!)
So what do we need to check to see if a transformation is linear?  Let's call your transformation $f$.

Does $f$ map a vector to a vector? (yes: it maps a tilted vector to a flat vector)
Given any two input vectors, $\vec v$ and $\vec u$, does $f(\vec v + \vec u) = f(\vec v) + f(\vec u)$ (yes if you break up the acceleration into two parts, it doesn't matter if you un-tilt them first and then add them, or add them and un-tilt them.  See if you can visualize that to make sure you agree with my claim)
Given any input vector $\vec v$ and a scalar (number) $c$, does $f(c\vec v) = cf(\vec v)$? (yes: If I make the tilted acceleration 2x larger, the untilted acceleration is 2x larger, but the direction wont change)

If you answer yes to those three questions, as we do for your problem, then the $f$ you are looking for is linear.  Now you can rejoice!  For now we can bring in power tools that mathematicians have made for you, like matrices.  You can show that any linear $f$ can be represented as a matrix.1  So that means now you know it makes sense to go explore the matrix based solution, like the one they arrived at in the linked question.
You can go through this process for any transformation problem, not just ones you already know to use matrices for.  See if it's a linear problem.  Life is easier if it is!
As for quaternions, yes you can use them.  However, the math behind them is more cryptic and their uses are limited to 3 dimensional rotations.  They have some really useful properties, but it is best to understand the linear math and why it works before we start mapping it into exotic domains like quaternions. (source: I work with quaternions regularly, and have to constantly explain to trained professionals the nuances of implementing rotations with them).
And as a neat addition beyond the linked question, its possible that you might not have just a tilt.  Depending on the quality of the mounting, it is possible to have a non-orthogonal sensor, where the x y and z axes are not quite at right angles.  Matrices can solve that, because the math is still linear, but quaternions cannot because they only support rotations.
1. Well, there's exceptions, like infinite dimensional linear transformations...but that's fancy stuff!

I really appreciate for your sincere answer! since I have poor knowledge with this, I will work on my task with your answer and I will comment if I find more problem or reach the goal!
